# Question regarding ternary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

How can the type of the following ternary relation $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ (set of all integers) be determined whether it is reflexive, transitive or symmetric ?

$$
R = \{ a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} : a \cdot b \cdot c < -1 \}  
$$

If the aforementioned properties are not applicable for a ternary relation, unlike binary relation, then what are the properties of a ternary relation?

I tried searching about the concept and the problem over the internet, but failed to get any.

A detailed answer would be helpful.

Comment: How do you define reflexive, transitive, symmetric for a ternary relation?

Comment: Yes that is I want to know. If these properties are not applicable for a terenary relation, unlike binary relation, then what are the properties of a terenary relation ?

Comment: Googling tells me there is such a thing as a [ternary equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_equivalence_relation) and definitions for these properties are given in that context.

Comment: Can i please be referred to few example questions with solutions on ternary and N-nary equivalence relations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_equivalence_relation)

the notions are defined as follows (I'll use $R(a,b,c)$ for $(a,b,c) \in R$), together they're called a ternary equivalence relation:

- **Symmetry**: $\forall a,b,c: R(a,b,c) \implies (R(b,c,a) \land R(c,b,a))$ So all permutations of arguments also hold; th elatter I would see as the most general form of the definition: for any permutation $\sigma \in S_3$ we have $R(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ implies $R(x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, x_{\sigma(3)})$
- **Reflexivity**: $\forall a,b: R(a,b,b)$ and this implies (if we have symmetry), the most general form of the definition if $|\{a,b,c\}| \neq 3$ we have that $R(a,b,c)$ holds.
- **Transitivity**: if $a \neq b$ and $R(a,b,c)$ and $R(a,b,d)$ then also $R(b,c,d)$.

The symmetry of your $R$ is evident, while $R(1,1,1)$ does not hold so reflexivity is out. I think transivity might fail too, look for examples..

Comment: Can i please be referred to few example questions with solutions on ternary and N-nary equivalence relations ?

Comment: @Aditya I presume you have a text book or notes? I just used Wikipedia...

Comment: Do you know of any online practice material or notes for this ?